# How many invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let the matrix
A=\begin{pmatrix}
* & * & * & *\\
* & * & * & *\\
0 & 0 & * & * \\
0 & 0 & * & * 
\end{pmatrix}.]
where every element * could be 1 or 0 . How many intertible matrices like that are?
The only idea that I have was to keep on the elements on the main diagonal 1 but with the others I do not what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so building on @SiongThyeGoh's answer, we get $|\rm{GL}(2,\mathbb Z_2)|^2=((2^2-1)(2^2-2))^2=36$.  But then we can put any matrix above the diagonal, so we multiply by $2^4$.  We get $16\cdot36=576$.

Comment: You don't solve the same problem as asked by the OP: in your case, a matrix with determinant $2$ for example is the same as a matrix with determinant $0$...

Comment: I don't follow.  How would I get a matrix of determinant $2$?  @JeanMarie

Comment: Besides, your result 576 is the good one. Therefore it mans may be that all determinants have values in $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: Right.  That's what I thought. @JeanMarie

Comment: Answer to your answer: we are converging... This remains to be established for your reduction of the problem from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$ is fully valid...

Comment: Sure.  Ok good.  It's pretty clear, I think, that those are the only possible determinants.  The diagonals multiply to $0$ or $1$, then you subtract.  So we have it. @JeanMarie  And working with just entries of $0$ and $1$ only is the same as working over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, I would say.  This seems to be fairly standard, with the hint in the other answer being key.

Answer (score 3):

Guide:

$$\det\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & C\end{bmatrix} = \det(A) \det(C)$$

Hence we should focus on studying how many possible choice of binary $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ are there such that $A$ is non-singular.